# PyGtk: Scrolllist with Entry, can I set an Id

Tags: gtk, signal

I have a scroll list on my window that I am going to insert 2 entry for each row, I am trying to understand how I can catch the entry that has been changed and update my array with this value.

I will explain what is my code:

- I have an array that has 2 fields: Name and Description
- Each row has 2 entry, Name and Description

When I am going to modify the row number 2 I want to update my object on my array:

rows[1].name = XXX
rows[1].description = YYY

Comment: I guess so that I can try with a custom signal, like:
entryName.connect("activate", self.enter_callback, entry,self.TYPE_NAME,id)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I created a custom signal that I am going to pass the id of the array.